# Having Trouble on getting showing shape on frame

Tags: java, swing, panel, frame, shapes

I managed to get the individual pattern to show on the panel. But now I would like to create a Token object ( which is the 2 lines inside a rectangle). I would like to create the Token in Panel. Using the token parameters, I would like to create a rectangle that will enclose the pattern in it. The game token will create the pattern which in turn will create the specific pattern. In this case the Cross Pattern.
What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I initialized things?

Here's the pattern I created

```
public  class CrossPattern  extends JPanel{
private Point2D.Double top;
private Point2D.Double bottom;
private Point2D.Double top1;
private Point2D.Double bottom1;
private Line2D.Double line1;
private Line2D.Double line2;
private Rectangle bbox;
public CrossPattern() 
{

     // correct  Cross pattern
     top= new Point2D.Double(bbox.getX(),bbox.getY()) ; 
     bottom= new Point2D.Double(bbox.getX()+bbox.getWidth(),bbox.getY()+bbox.getWidth());  // correct Cross Pattern

     top1= new Point2D.Double(bbox.getX()+bbox.getWidth(),bbox.getY());  // Correct cross Patt
     bottom1= new Point2D.Double(bbox.getX(),bbox.getY()+bbox.getHeight());   // correct Cross Patt

     line1= new Line2D.Double(top,bottom);   // correct Cross Patt
     line2= new Line2D.Double(top1,bottom1);   // Correct cross patt




}
public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
{


g2.draw(this.line1);
g2.draw(this.line2);


}



}
```

Here's the pattern that will create the specific pattern within the dimensions of the box.

```
public class Pattern 
{


  private CrossPattern pattern1;

  int type;

Random random = new Random();



  public  Pattern(Rectangle bbox)
  {
  int num= 0; //set random num a int value from 0-2
  bbox = bbox;

  if(num==0)
  {
   pattern1 = new CrossPattern();

}
```

Here's my game token where I'll implement the location and size

```
public class GameToken implements VisibleShape
{
  private boolean visible;
  public    Rectangle bbox;
  private Pattern pattern;
  private   Color color;
  Random random = new Random();

   public GameToken(int x, int y, int width, int height) 
   {
    bbox = new Rectangle ( x,y,width,height); 
   pattern= new Pattern(bbox); 


  }
```

And here is the panel where I'll be creating the token

```
public class GameTokenPanel extends JPanel {
private CrossPattern patternt;
private Rectangle rect;
private GameToken token1;
public GameTokenPanel()
{

 token1= new GameToken(50,50,25,25);
repaint();

}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{


super.paint(g);
Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;

patternt.draw(g2);

}




}
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Your code generates a compiler exception at `g2.draw(this.line2);`, because `line2` is undefined and a `NullPointerException` at `g2.draw(this.line1);` because `line1` (and assume `line2`) aren't initalised, because you've shadowed your variables...

```
private static class CrossPattern {
    //...
    private Line2D.Double line1;

    public CrossPattern() {
        // Oh, look, you've redefined `line1` as a local variable!
        Line2D.Double line1 = new Line2D.Double(top, bottom);   // correct 
        //...
```

Get rid of the redecleartion of the `line1`, `top`, `bottom`, `top1`, `bottom1` and `line2` ...

Unless you have a particularly good reason for doing so, you should override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` in your `GameTokenPanel`.

Instead of using `FRAME_WIDTH` and `FRAME_HEIGHT`, you should override the `getPreferredSize` method of `GameTokenPanel` and return the preferred "view" size you want.  Currently, the viewable area of the you component will be `FRAME_WIDTH - frame decorations horizontal insets` and `FRAME_HEIGHT - frame decorations vertical insets`, which may not meet you expectations.

Having said that, you should be passing `patternt` the current size of the component, so it can make decisions about how best to render the pattern...